# Global Python package

Tags: python

so I have this package. In the cmd I go to `hp@HP-PC C:\Users\hp\Documents\scripts`:

```
hp@HP-PC C:\Users\hp\Documents\scripts
> python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import toolzz.printer as t
>>> t.printz()
5
```

Everything is working fine but I want to have a directory in which I could add my scripts and be able to open my cmd->python->import my package and do whatever I am going to do and not get this instead:

```
hp@HP-PC C:\Users\hp
> python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import toolzz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'toolzz'
>>>
```

PS: keep in mind I have added the directory `scripts` to the path and I have global bat files which work

Comment: did you try running `python2`? installing a package for python 2 doesn't install it for python 3

Comment: You need to actually *install* your package

Comment: You mean you want to add `C:\Users\hp\Documents\scripts` to the Python module search path?

Comment: how can I install this package ?

Comment: How can I add the package the ... "Python path" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
python -m site
```

It'll list 2 important pieces of information:

- The Python module search path, `sys.path`
- The location for the `USER_SITE` directory, and wether or not this exists.

Python looks for modules along those locations. Put your module in a `sys.path` location (in one that ends in `site-packages` preferably), or make sure you created the `USER_SITE` directory and put your code in there.

And you can always extend the path by setting the [`PYTHONPATH` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

Comment: Can I add a new element to the sys.path

Comment: @murloc: sure; added a link to the PYTHONPATH env variable.